# modal popup not showing from code behind

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updtpnlacademic" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<td>
<asp:GridView ID="gdvwAcademic1"  runat="server" OnRowCommand="gdvwAcademic1_RowCommand" OnRowDeleting="gdvwAcademic1_RowDeleting" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="100%" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlign="Center">

    <Columns>
      ....Other column fields
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"  ShowHeader="false">
          <ItemTemplate>                                                           
              <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnacademicdelete" CommandName="Delete" OnClick="imgbtnacademicdelete_Click" CommandArgument='<%# ((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>' ToolTip="Delete" runat="server" ImageAlign="Top" ImageUrl="~/Images/delete.png" Width="30" Height="25"/>
          </ItemTemplate>                                                        
      </asp:TemplateField>                                      
     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:Button ID="btndummy" runat="server" Visible="false" />
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpacademic" runat="server" TargetControlID="btndummy" PopupControlID="Panel2"  CancelControlID="btnacademicClose"  BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender> 

<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" HorizontalAlign="Center" style = "display:none">
   <span style="color:white; font-family:'Bookman Old Style'; font-weight:bold;">Really Want To Delete This Record...!</span><br /><br /><br /><br />
         <asp:Button ID="btnconfirmacademicdelete" OnClick="btnconfirmacademicdelete_Click" CssClass="BStyle" Font-Bold="true" runat="server" Text="Yes" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
         <asp:Button ID="btnacademicClose" Font-Bold="true" runat="server" CssClass="BStyle" Text="Cancel" />
</asp:Panel> 
</td>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And following code as in the code behind ....

```
protected void gdvwAcademic1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        mpacademic.Show();
       //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("RowDeleting clicked after this modal popup should be displayed.....!");              
    }
```

It only show messagebox on event if uncomment messagebox but not showing modal popup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpacademic" runat="server" TargetControlID="btndummy" PopupControlID="Panel2"  CancelControlID="btnacademicClose"  BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
```

The `TargetControlID` property is set to `btndummy` and

```
<asp:Button ID="btndummy" runat="server" Visible="false" />
```

`btndummy` is not rendering since `Visible` property is set to false.

Try to replace

```
<asp:Button ID="btndummy" runat="server" Visible="false" />
```

With

```
<asp:Button ID="btndummy" runat="server" style="display:none" />
```